# why blt instruction don't work? Mars mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm tryng to open a file with a list of contacts, and when i verify if are with the correctly format (name ',' number), i use a bgt and a blt instruction to see if the chars are bigger than z or lower than a, so rejected. but when i do this, my blt instruction doesn't work. when its executed jump do the label, and if before i have a beq with a value bigger than the blt, he jumps to.

```
Maiuscula:
lb $t0,0($a0)       #carrega a0 em t0
#slt $t1, $zero,$t0 #carater de t0 com zero
beq $t0,$zero,END
nop #se t1=0 entao, t0 tem o carater nulo, logo END
li $t3,0x41     # A maiusculo em ascii
li $t4,0x5a     # Z maiusculo em ascii
slt $t5,$t0,$t4
bgt $t0,$t4,Erro    #tinha bgt
nop

blt $t0,$t3,zero    #here is the error
nop

j minuscula
nop
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `slt $t5,$t0,$t4`, as you are using pseudoinstruction `bgt`/`blt` which already uses `slt` + `bne` to accomplish the task.
Aside from that, your code will:

- Branch to Erro if the character is > 'A'
- Branch to zero if the character is < 'Z'
- Otherwise, it will branch to minuscula

So there seems to be some logic errors there...

For example, you should use `bge` instead of `bgt` and `ble` instead of `blt` because otherwise you will not check 'A' and 'Z' correctly.

Aside from that, I guess the logic is not doing what you meant it to do...